# C# XML Deserialization with multiple namespaces in element names and attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xml-deserialization

I am trying to read in this piece of xml code and for the most part it comes in correctly. The issue I am having is around the "element" element and the namespace with the type attribute.

XML File I am trying to Read in (text.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <archimate:model xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:archimate="http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate" name="ACME" 
     id="38f940a6-9fc7-4619-9806-fd4d48397af7" version="4.0.0">
    <folder name="Strategy" id="ffc905fd-a78c-4311-b2f6-a188c00ed10a" type="strategy"/>
    <folder name="Business" id="0d806081-438f-4ae5-86d9-8ff5ee4e9f1a" type="business"/>
    <folder name="Application" id="3566e95c-c070-46bb-bde3-f6017ae49dc1" type="application"/>
    <folder name="Technology &amp; Physical" id="4fabc4fa-a882-4843-ae69-170b66df7685" type="technology"/>
    <folder name="Motivation" id="ce5e0874-1c06-41c1-9b95-eec6558afa89" type="motivation">
      <element xsi:type="archimate:Principle" name="Secure the Whole" id="9546e727-f9f7-402a-a4a2-50519d697d75"/>
    </folder>
 </archimate:model>
```

The code for labeling my model for XML input and output:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace archimate_reporter.Models
{
    public class Folder
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "element")]
        public List<Element> Element { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="element")]
    public class Element
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Form=XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace="http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "model", Namespace = "http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
    public class Model
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "folder", Namespace = "")]
        public List<Folder> Folder { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "archimate", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Archimate { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }       
}
```

Calling program for testing:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using archimate_reporter.Models;

namespace archimate_reporter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program t = new Program();
            t.DeserializeObject("resource//test.xml");
        }

        private void DeserializeObject(string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new
            XmlSerializer(typeof(Model));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);

            Model i;
            i = (Model)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack error the program is throwing:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (11, 6). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='Principle', namespace='http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate', at <element xmlns=''>.
    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderModel.Read2_Element(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderModel.Read3_Folder(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderModel.Read4_Model(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderModel.Read5_model()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
    at archimate_reporter.Program.DeserializeObject(String filename) in D:\mmcke\workspace\archimate-reporter\Program.cs:line 36
    at archimate_reporter.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\mmcke\workspace\archimate-reporter\Program.cs:line 16
```

Comment: So you need to review your namespace usage on all levels?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your model to provide something to deserialize the `archimate:Principle` type into. Also, you need to correct the namespace of the Type attribute on `Element`.

Based on your XML, I've assumed `Element` is a base class and the `type` attribute indicates the super type to use which I've put in a new class called `Principle`. If you don't want a separate class for that though, you can just have `Element`, but you need to give it the `XmlType` attribute to tell the `Serializer` to use it when it sees `xsi:type="archimate:Principle"`.

```
[XmlType("Principle", Namespace = "http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
public class Principle : Element
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "element", Namespace = "http://www.archimatetool.com/archimate")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Principle))]
public class Element
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I modified it slightly by moving the Type property to the Principle class to also capture the type attribute string value.  Works Great!